Is there a C++20 concept that will be called when a function is used from a certain library?
I want all calls to functions from a certain library to be wrapped with a call to my function.
For example, whenever a function from the library <glad/glad.h> is called, my function log() is called before running the library function.
I have been reading about c++20 concepts. Can these achieve the task without using macros?
I have been looking at functions like these:
template<typename glFunction, typename ReturnType, typename... Params>
auto glCallImpl(const char* filename, const std::uint_fast32_t line, glFunction function, ReturnType& returnValue, Params... params)
->typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<void, decltype(function(params...))>, bool>
{
    returnValue = function(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    return check_gl_errors(function, filename, line);
}

They don't seem to be using the most up-to-date features of C++ though. I would like to use concepts where possible.

If these are global functions, you can do better:
template<auto function>
struct Call;
template<typename Return, typename... Args, Return(function)(Args...)>
struct Call<function> {
    std::expected<Return, std::error_code> operator()(Args&&... args, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) const {
        auto returnvalue = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        // Assuming check_gl_errors also returns std::expected<Return, std::error_code>
        return check_gl_errors(returnvalue, loc.file_name(), loc.line());
    }
};

template<auto function>
constexpr Call<function> call{};

// Usage:
call<::gl_do_stuff>(1, 2, 3);

See godbolt.
And here's the C++20 version. Since you're just returning a bool, no error details, in the code in your question, I'm assuming that check_gl_errors logs the error details for you:
template<auto function>
struct Call;
template<typename Return, typename... Args, Return(function)(Args...)>
struct Call<function> {
    std::optional<Return> operator()(Args&&... args, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) const {
        auto returnvalue = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        // Assuming check_gl_errors also returns std::expected<Return, std::error_code>
        return check_gl_errors(returnvalue, loc.file_name(), loc.line());
    }
};

template<auto function>
constexpr Call<function> call{};

See godbolt. Alternatively to optional, you can always go the route of returning Return directly and throwing exceptions in case of errors.
The reason to make this a callable struct instead of a function is that this gives us argument deduction based on the function we're trying to wrap. So if the function takes an unsigned int and we pass -5, that's a compiler warning at the call site. If we were to deduce the args based on what's passed, -5 would be deduced as int, which at worst leads to a undiagnosed unexpected misbehavior.

this is going into c++23 and I was determined to stick with 20 for now.

I think the only 23 feature I use is expected. Assuming you don't need error details (since you're just returning a bool in your original code), you could just switch it to optional. The rest should be C++20, unless I'm missing something.

Also, you're saying you're determined to stick with 20 as if you have no concrete reason to. Generally the wisdom is: use the highest version of the standard that's available to you, unless you have a good reason not to. So if you can use 23, I suggest you do it.
